# public and private key files (.pkr,.skr)

Tags: pgp

i am new to PGP and want to implement encryption/decryption in one requirement. i googled it and decided to use Boynce Castle algo. But when i am trying to understand it, i confused at how i will get the .pkr and .skr files. i just downloaded required jars and program and when tried to run it shows me file not found. i was not aware so by myself i created .pkr and .skr files (converting from .txt) but i think it should be in some format and that should generated by some mechanism. can some explain me about this? How i can proceed.. ?

Answer (score 4):

If you have PGP Desktop installed on the same Windows computer as the PGP Command Line, and you installed PGP Desktop to the default directory, then PGP Command Line will automatically locate and use your existing keyrings. If you are not using PGP Keyrings from a PGP Desktop product, you will need to create blank keyring files. To do so open a command prompt and type the following command:

```
pgp --create-keyrings
```

This will create a pubring.pkr (public keyring) and secring.skr (private keyring) file in the default keyring location. For Windows this is in the My Documents>PGP folder. This article will use [ ] to identify information that you will need to enter that is specific to your individual keys.

After that, you will need to create a key pair. To create a key pair using PGP Command Line follow these steps:

On the command line, enter:

```
pgp --gen-key [user ID] --key-type [key type] --bits [bits #] --passphrase [passphrase]
```

NOTE: Any information that contains spaces must be contained inside quotation marks.

Example: The following example will show you how to create a 2048 Bit RSA key for Joe User, an employee of ACME Corp, with the passphrase "my passphrase".

```bash
pgp --gen-key "Joe User" --key-type RSA --bits 2048 --passphrase "my passphrase"
```

PGP Command line will now generate your keypair. You should see your Key ID (i.e. 0X12345678), and a message that the key was successfully generated.

NOTE: To display your new keypair enter the following command:

```
pgp --list-keys
```

This will display all the keys that are found on your keyring.

After the key pair is generated and identified, it is important to export the public portion (public key) of the key pair so others can import your public key and encrypt to you. NOTES: Once you have exported your public key to a file, it is easy to distribute. You can attach it to an email, paste the public key block text into the body of an email message (open with Notepad), or copy to a CD, for example. To export your public key you will need to have information about the key in order to identify it, which will be referred to in this document as (input). You can use the key ID (i.e. 0x12345678), user ID (i.e. "Joe User"), or a portion of the user ID, (i.e. Joe). To export the key, do the following:

```
pgp --export (input)
```

PGP Command Line responds by exporting keys as ASCII armor (.asc) files into the directory currently active on the command line.

The following examples will show you how to export your public key using your key ID and user ID.

```
pgp --export 0x12345678
pgp --export "Joe User"
```

You may import a public key from an ASCII Armor file (.asc) or from a text file, the process is the same for both. The file containing the key(s) to be imported must be in the current directory. As with exporting a key, this will be referred to as (input) in the examples. Both public and private keys will be imported if they exist in the file. If a key being imported already exists in the local keyring, the keys are merged. Import Key From File:

```
pgp --import (input)
```

PGP Command Line responds as follows: Joe User.asc:import key {0:key imported as 0x12345678 Joe User}

The following examples will show you how to import a key from an ASCII Armor file (.asc) and from a text file containing the PGP key block.

```bash
pgp --import "Joe User.asc"
pgp --import "PGP Joe.txt"
```

Comment: Where could I download pgp desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Those files are public and private (secret in OpenPGP terminology) keyrings respectively. They contain collections of public and private keys. You usually generate a keypair (a pair of public and private key) or several keypairs for your own use, and other people do the same. Then they can give you their *public* keys and you create a public keyring from those keys. Public keyring is then used to encrypt data for recipients or to verify other people's daa signatures.

Private keyring is composed from your private keys which you generate. You use private keyring for signing your data, and you can give corresponding public keys to other people so that they could encrypt data for you (which you then decrypt using your private keys).

I believe BouncyCastle has key generation functions, or you can use GnuPG application or PGP Desktop to generate keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the examples for OpenPGP key generation that ship with the BouncyCastle library.

They are located at :

[bouncy castle sources]\src\org\bouncycastle\openpgp\examples\RSAKeyPairGenerator.java

[bouncy castle sources]\src\org\bouncycastle\openpgp\examples\DSAElGamalKeyRingGenerator.java

Example code that uses the keys can be found at:

[bouncy castle sources]\src\org\bouncycastle\openpgp\examples\KeyBasedFileProcessor.java